# What am I? (word modification)

Tags: riddle

Add a letter, and I become that which helps create me.

Take away two, and I become soup.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you a

> photo?

"Add a letter, and I become that which helps create me."

> Photon (also *photog*, slang for *photographer*)

"Take away two, and I become soup."

> Pho

Comment: Nicely done! Did the second hint make it too easy?

Comment: @gnovice, in a way. I don't really know much about soups, so I looked up a list of soups and the only ones that looked like they could be part of a longer word were gumbo and pho. This really reduced the number of possibilities, but I don't consider that a fault or defect. Not all puzzles need to be super hard, though; this was a fun little puzzle for us to relax in a lazy afternoon, and it served well for this purpose.